# store the form values of textboxes automatically in database

Tags: c#

In c# windows application, I want to store the textbox values automaticaly into a database table as they are being entered.the database row should be updated as the user fills in all the textboxes. how to do it?

Comment: what about the overheads this approach will generate . is your situation really demand this functionality. you have to make connection every time as use types so much overhead .might be you need a different solution so think about this once again .

Comment: I would have to see a business case for this one, as this idea has "code smell" written all over it.

Answer (score 1):

your question is really vague and generic. I assume you are working with Windows Forms.

Start reading some of the articles linked here: [Windows Forms Data Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx)

especially those about Navigate and Binding Data in Windows Forms.

Comment: in textchanged event only the first letter of the first textbox entered is being stored. it should be that whenver the cursor position is changed from the first textbox, the database row should get populated.what is the event for that?

Comment: no, surely not. You should NOT execute an UPDATE against the database at every single key press. The BindingSource allows you to "cache" the changes locally and update the database at once either when clicking save or when navigating to another record.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save it as they are changing, you can use event `TextBox.TextChanged`:

```
void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string text = this.textBox1.Text;
    // your saving
}
```

Ok. If you want to save it as the input "is finished", you can use the event `TextBox.Leave` the same way.

Comment: in textchanged event only the first letter of the first textbox entered is being stored. it should be that whenver the cursor position is changed from the first textbox, the database row should get populated.what is the event for that?